# Add custom View as marker in Google Maps API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've developed a class that inherits from a View class and I want it to serve as a marker on a MapFragment/MapView from a Google Maps API v2. As I recall, such thing was possible in API v1 and even now it is possible on iOS. I'm looking for something like this:

```
MapView map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
CircleTimerView myTimer = new CircleTimerView(this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight(), geoPoint, LayoutParams.BOTTOM);
map.addView(myTimer,lp);
```

My custom View is animated and it is a key feature of my app.

My question is: Is it possible for a current state of Google Maps API? Or should I try to obtain API v1 key and work with something that was deprecated?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I try to obtain API v1 key and work with something that was deprecated?

You cannot obtain new keys for API v1.

> My custom View is animated and it is a key feature of my app.

You cannot have animated `Marker` icon unless you repeatedly change the icon using `Marker.setIcon`.

> Is it possible for a current state of Google Maps API?

You can use a `View` as icon if you draw it into a `Bitmap` first.

This library from Chris Broadfoot can greatly help you with that task:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

See this video for what the lib can do: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb2X9IjjZpM

Or the new website: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

Comment: That is a great advice, thank you very much, Maciej. I'll let you know if that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in order to customize / use your own custom maker on google maps api v2 you could write the code as follows:

in onCreate declare the marker:

```
    userIcon = R.drawable.red;
```

and then i used it where you need it, in my case i used it in a method:

```
    if(userMarker!=null) userMarker.remove();

    userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(lastLatLng)
    .title("You are here")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
    .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
    theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 100, null);

    CameraUpdate center=
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng);
        CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
       theMap.moveCamera(center);
        theMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

hope this helped. good luck

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue these days and you should do the switch for v2 as you can do all the same stuff from v1 easier + many new features.

MapView has been replaced with the new GoogleMap-Objecttype.

A very detailed and decent Tutorial site can be found [HERE!](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html)